# Backbone.js not rendering JSON -

Tags: php, json, backbone.js

I have to code:

```
window.TicketCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Tickets,
    url:"/index.php/tickets/viewJSON"
});
window.TicketsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:'div',
    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);

    },
    render:function(eventName){
        _.each(this.model.models, function(ticket){
            $(this.el).append(new TicketListItemView({model:ticket}).render().el);
        },this);
        return this;
    }
});
window.TicketListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    template:_.template($('#tickets-list-item').html()),
    render:function (eventName){
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON));
        return this;
    }
});


var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{
        "":"list"
    },
    list:function(){
        window.alert("alright");
        this.ticketList = new TicketCollection();
        this.ticketLists = this.ticketList.get();

        this.ticketListView = new TicketListView({model:this.ticketList});
        $("#ticketListHolder").html(this.ticketListView.render().el);
    },
});
var app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
});
```

My php is as follows:

```
<?php header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("ticketID"=>"test", "ticketName"=>"1"));?>
```

The response from the php is:

```
[{"ticketID":"1","ticketName":"Fix the admin system"}]
```

HTML:

```
<div id="ticketListHolder">
    #


</div>
<script type="text/template" id="tickets-list-item">
        <div class="supTicket ticketHolder nobg">
        <div class="issueType">
        <span class="issueInfo"><%= ticketName %></span>
        <span class="issueNum">[ #<%= ticketID %>] - <%= fullName %></span>
        </div>
        </div>
</script>
```

I get the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ticketName is not defined`, it appears that it's not parsing the json, instead reading it as one string block. Why is this error occuring, when my JSON is returning the correct data.

Comment: Where is your assumption _"it appears that it's not parsing the json, instead reading it as one string block"_ based on?. I think you need to debug a little to see where is the first point the state of the system is not the expected one, a few `console.log` here and there could help you. For example _how does `ticket` look like into this block `_.each(this.model.models, function(ticket){..}`?_. Also check your _JS console_ to check the _responses_ of the _AJAX calls_.

Comment: The AJAX call responds fine, a `console.log` on `this.ticketList.fetch()` ( see @nikoshr's answer) returns `responseText: "{"ticketID":"test","ticketName":"1"}"`

Comment: how does `ticket` look like into this block `_.each(this.model.models, function(ticket){..}`? I want to see if the `ticket` reference is what we are expecting and if its _attributes_ are properly filled.

Comment: I think @nikoshr has found the issue: _"`this.model.toJSON` should have been `this.model.toJSON()`"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `collection.fetch` anywhere. Your router probably should look like this

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{
        "":"list"
    },
    list:function(){
        window.alert("alright");
        this.ticketList = new TicketCollection();

        this.ticketListView = new TicketListView({
                model:this.ticketList,
                el:$("#ticketListHolder") // I directly assigned #ticketListHolder as the el
        });

        this.ticketList.fetch();
    },
});
```

And a Fiddle with a mostly working version of your code http://jsfiddle.net/Cc9Ad/2/
Some points you should check:

- your ListView and your ItemView were the other way round,
- as Daniel Aranda said in his answer, try to use collections and models for their intended purpose,
- this.model.toJSON should have been this.model.toJSON()
- set defaults on your models, fullName is not defined and would break the templating engine if used in this state

The revised code

```
window.Tickets=Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        fullName :"No full name"
    }
});
window.TicketCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Tickets,
    url:"/index.php/tickets/viewJSON"
});


window.TicketsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:'li',
    template:_.template($('#tickets-list-item').html()),

    initialize: function () {
    },
    render:function(eventName){
        console.log
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
window.TicketListView = Backbone.View.extend({   
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);

    },

    render:function (){
        this.collection.each( function(ticket){
            $(this.el).append(new TicketsView({model:ticket}).render().el);
        },this);

        return this;
    }
});


        var ticketList = new TicketCollection();

        var ticketListView = new TicketListView({
                collection:ticketList,
                el:$("#ticketListHolder")
        });

// ticketList.fetch();
ticketList.reset([
    {"ticketID":"1","ticketName":"Fix the admin system"},
    {"ticketID":"2","ticketName":"The ticket 2"}
]);
```

Comment: I don't receive an error with this code, however the template isnt populated. Would this be a seperate problem?

Comment: @rickyduck There are quite a few things that go wrong in there. I'll try to provide a Fiddle with a working version.

Comment: @rickyduck I modified my answer with the Fiddle

Comment: _"`this.model.toJSON` should have been `this.model.toJSON()`"_ I think this is main issue :)

Comment: @fguillen I think Daniel Aranda wrote it first :)

Comment: Having it the wrong way round was apparent to be the major cause as well. This code works perfectly, and I will disect it and learn an awful lot from this. Thanks so much to everyone!

Comment: @nikoshr... `ticketList.reset` - how do I make this default to the dynamically loaded JSON set from the URL?

Comment: Ignore me - its uncommenting `ticketList.fetch();`

Answer (score 1):

Model is not the same than collection.

You are trying to use a Collection as a Model.

Check this example:
http://danielarandaochoa.com/backboneexamples/blog/2012/02/22/real-world-usage-of-a-backbone-collection/

Also to fix your specific issue, pass to your template an object instead of a Backbone.Model

```
 $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

You was missing the parenthesis.

But as I said, I recommend you to read the article explaining how to use the collections.

Comment: @rickyduck I double checked your code and I think that your issue is that you was missing parenthesis when trying to convert your Model into a JSON object for your template.

Comment: Ok, thats a great article. Will read through it now. I tried it with parenthesis, made no difference.

Comment: (sorry btw - Backbone is a new thing for me and a bit confusing)

Comment: Check also the code that you pasted. In the each you use "TicketListItemView" but you only declare window.TicketListView. Anyway I think that after read the article, the better could be to write new Views, and using the reset event instead of a manual each as you are doing. :)

Comment: Neither did that work. I will take your advise and read that tutorial, hopefully meaning my end product not only works, but is correct as well.

Comment: Are you using Chrome, and Chrome developers tool? there you could debug. Also doing console.log( this.model ); and console.log( this.model.toJSON() ); is kind of helpful to trap the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I use JSON.parse() function to parse the data sent by the PHP.

```
var a = $.ajax({
    url:"/index.php/tickets/viewJSON",
    async:false,
    cache:false
}).responseText;

jsonData = JSON.parse(a);


then use  _.each to loop jsonData then push each data to your model.
```

Comment: How would I use _.each to loop?

Comment: If you are using Backbone, there is not any need of use JSON.parse functions, Backbone does it.

Comment: Just like how you did with your model:
 _.each(jsonData, function(ticket){